# How to get a random number from compiler

Tags: java, random

I'm creating a simple card game where cards are created using random number. I want to use the random number as a score int. Is there a way to add the random number used to generate specif card? For example random number for level:5. Totalscore = totalscore + RandomNumber.

Card Class

```
public class clsCard {
    //Main variables of my program
    private int value;
    private int level, object;
    private final int MaxFaceValue= 10;
    private static String[] objects =  {"Joker","hearts","spades","diamond","clubs"};
    private static String[] levels = {"Joker","Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"};

    public clsCard()  {
        this.level= (int)(Math.random()*levels.length);
        this.object= (int)(Math.random()*objects.length);
    }

    public @Override String toString() { 
        if(levels[level].equals("Joker") || objects[object].equals("Joker"))
            return "Joker";
        else
            return levels[level] + " of " + objects[object];
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public int getObject() {
        return object;
    }
}
```

Main program

```
clsCard cardFace = new clsCard();           
System.out.println(cardFace);
```

Comment: `javascript` != `java`

Comment: "*How to get a random number from compiler*" - The compiler gives you bytecode, provided you pass it some valid java code. Nothing else.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking - you could try using a Map<int, whatever_your_card_is> and mapping an Integer from 1-12 with a card. Then use your randomly generated number from 1-12 to select your card. Here are the maps doc to have a look at. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: @bartlomiej-kaczmarek this is the tip we generally give our students mate: 1- understand the problem before start coding 2- break down the problem into subproblem  3- solve each subproblem separately. 4- plug each subproblem together to create a working system.